# How to get query execution plans from spark history server using rest APIs?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can see **SQL** tab on **spark history server** which has all the ** query execution plans** in **details** section but there are **no rest APIs** mentioned to get them as **Json** object using code in **spark monitoring and instrumentation** page.

Link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

for example, I can get easily get **job** and **stage** data as json using **http:localhost:18080/applications/[app-id]/jobs** and **http:localhost:18080/applications/[app-id]/stages** rest APIs.

How to get execution plans as json object using rest APIs?